# Leviton Triplex unavailable/discontinued. Alternatives?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

It appears that the [Leviton Triplex outlets](http://www.levitonproducts.com/catalog/model_AC320.htm) are no longer available and the product is listed as discontinued.   *My best guess is that they weren't technically code compliant?*

They were a rather brilliant solution for fitting 3 ground NEMA compatible outlets into the space of a normal outlet.

Are there alternative solutions available?

Edit:  The goal is to avoid messing with an outside wall.  I have an existing weatherproof outlet where I need 3 plugs.   Making it bigger is possible (and in my range of skills), but I'd rather avoid doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New box (either add, or replace smaller with larger), pair of duplex, 4 outlets.

Sure, you want not to do that, but it works, and always has worked.

If you can handle it being 15 amp rather than 20 and a large pricetag, Legrand adorne makes what's claimed to be a 1-gang triplex pop-up outlet. Never seen one in person, and I'd wonder about long-term reliability with it having moving parts.

[image: Triplex pop-up]

Comment: Ooh... that's neat.   Unfortunately, won't work for me as I wanted a solution to fit an existing outdoor outlet box.   Going with a pair of duplex involves a lot of wall cutting, etc,etc that I wanted to avoid.

Comment: May be simpler to cut a new hole for a new duplex box rather than trying to enlarge the current hole to be a quad. Or bring one out as a surface mount somewhere nearby.